# Saving User a/c details from parse on device for offline use. Swift 3

Tags: parse-platform, swift3, local-datastore

I have setup the parse & all, sign up works perfectly as needed. But after that, I am unable to get the user details back on device for offline use.

I need those objects offline once the user Logs In / Signs Up.

**Class Name : `User`**

**Objects:**

1. `coverPhoto` : **Image.png** (saved as File)
2. `profilePicture` : **Image.png** (saved as File)
3. `usersUsername` : String
4. `username` / `email` : String
5. `firstName` : String
6. `middleName` : String
7. `lastName` : String
8. `mobileNumber` : String
9. `birthDate` : String
10. `gender` : String
11. `about` : String

I tried to store it using `UserDefaults.standard.set(_variable name_, forKey: "String")` but didn't work. :\

This is what i am geting repeatedly.
[image: 1]]

This is what i wrote:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
    activityIndicator.layer.zPosition = 1
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    if email.text == "" || password.text == "" {

        createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please enter your username & password!")

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    } else {

        PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: email.text!, password: password.text!, block: { (suser, error) in



            if error != nil {

                var displayErrorMessage = "Some Error Occured! Please Try Again Later!"

                if let errorMessage = error as? NSError {
                    displayErrorMessage = errorMessage.userInfo["error"] as! String
                }
                self.createAlert(title: "Dang it!", message: displayErrorMessage)

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            } else {

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainFunction", sender: nil)

                let query = PFUser.query()

                query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

                    if error != nil {

                        print(error)

                    } else if let users = objects {

                        for object in users {

                            if let user = object as? PFUser {

                                if user.objectId != PFUser.current()?.objectId {

                                    if let email = user.username {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
                                    }

                                    if let coverFile = user["coverPhoto"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(coverFile, forKey: "coverPhoto")
                                    }

                                    if let profileFile = user["profilePicture"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(profileFile, forKey: "profilePicture")
                                    }

                                    if let firstName = user["firstName"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
                                    }

                                    if let middleName = user["middleName"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(middleName, forKey: "middleName")
                                    }

                                    if let lastName = user["lastName"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
                                    }

                                    if let mobileNumber = user["mobileNumber"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(mobileNumber, forKey: "mobileNumber")
                                    }

                                    if let birthday = user["BirthDate"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(birthday, forKey: "BirthDate")
                                    }

                                    if let gender = user["gender"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(gender, forKey: "gender")
                                    }

                                    if let aboutYou = user["about"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(aboutYou, forKey: "about")
                                    }

                                    if let username = user["usersUsername"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: "username")
                                    }

                                    gloFirstName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firstName") as! String
                                    gloMiddleName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "middleName") as! String
                                    gloLastName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastName") as! String
                                    gloMobNumber = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "mobileNumber") as! String
                                    gloEmail = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email") as! String
                                    gloUName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "username") as! String
                                    gloBirthDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "BirthDate") as! String
                                    gloGenderStr = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "gender") as! String
                                    gloAbout = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "about") as! String

                                    if let coverImageData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "coverPhoto"),
                                        let coverPhoto = UIImage(data: coverImageData as! Data){

                                        gloCoverImage = coverPhoto

                                    }


                                    if let profileImageData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profilePicture"),
                                        let profilePicture = UIImage(data: profileImageData as! Data){
                                        gloProfilePicture = profilePicture

                                    }


                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                })

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            }

        })

    }

}
```

I am in a bind here.

***EDIT:***

[image: BreakPoint]

***EDIT#2:***

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Highlighted Code :**

```
 let query = PFUser.query()

                query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

                    if error != nil {

                        print(error)

                    } else if let users = objects {

                        for object in users {

                            if let user = object as? PFUser {
                                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
                                if user.objectId != PFUser.current()?.objectId {

                                    if let email = user.username {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
                                    }

                                    if let coverFile = user["coverPhoto"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(coverFile, forKey: "coverPhoto")
                                    }

                                    if let profileFile = user["profilePicture"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(profileFile, forKey: "profilePicture")
                                    }

                                    if let firstName = user["firstName"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
                                    }

                                    if let middleName = user["middleName"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(middleName, forKey: "middleName")
                                    }

                                    if let lastName = user["lastName"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
                                    }

                                    if let mobileNumber = user["mobileNumber"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(mobileNumber, forKey: "mobileNumber")
                                    }

                                    if let birthday = user["BirthDate"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(birthday, forKey: "BirthDate")
                                    }

                                    if let gender = user["gender"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(gender, forKey: "gender")
                                    }

                                    if let aboutYou = user["about"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(aboutYou, forKey: "about")
                                    }

                                    if let username = user["usersUsername"] {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: "username")
                                    }

                                    gloFirstName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firstName") as! String
                                    gloMiddleName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "middleName") as! String
                                    gloLastName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastName") as! String
                                    gloMobNumber = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "mobileNumber") as! String
                                    gloEmail = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email") as! String
                                    gloUName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "username") as! String
                                    gloBirthDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "BirthDate") as! String
                                    gloGenderStr = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "gender") as! String
                                    gloAbout = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "about") as! String

                                    if let coverImageData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "coverPhoto"),
                                        let coverPhoto = UIImage(data: coverImageData as! Data){

                                        gloCoverImage = coverPhoto

                                    }


                                    if let profileImageData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profilePicture"),
                                        let profilePicture = UIImage(data: profileImageData as! Data){
                                        gloProfilePicture = profilePicture

                                    }


                                }//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

                            }

                        }

                    }

                })
```

Comment: The issue is that the app is crashing because it unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, correct? Can you post the line where this crash occurs?

Comment: @nathan I am not really sure if this is what you need - ![link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofioG.png). If not please guide me

Comment: In the Xcode Debug Navigator you should be able to determine which line of _your_ code is causing the issue.

Comment: @nathan i've updated my code complete upto the `@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)` function's end and the debug [navigator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Kwm.png) which [highlights all the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dot7C.png) i mention in the **Edit#2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, solved it. This

`if user.objectId != PFUser.current()?.objectId {`

should've been this,

`if user.objectId == PFUser.current()?.objectId {`

since i needed my currently logged in account details to show up.

Also images can't be saved to `UserDefaults`. So just load it in every time you open the app and store it in a `var myVariableName = UIImage()` along with few `if` statement checks you can force unwrap it to this: `var myVariableName = UIImage()!`

Thanks Anyway!